# Sorted Map Iteration in Go Templates?

Tags: html, templates, go, hugo

I'm building a website in Go, using the [Hugo static site generator](http://gohugo.io/). What I'm trying to do is build a dynamic navigation bar for my web pages.

Here's what I'm doing:

In my `config.yml` file, I've defined a Map of links that I'd like to appear in my navbar -- here's what this file looks like:

```
baseurl: "https://www.rdegges.com/"
languageCode: "en-us"
title: "Randall Degges"
params:
  navLinks: {"Twitter": "https://twitter.com/rdegges", "Facebook": "https://www.facebook.com/rdegges", "Google+": "https://plus.google.com/109157194342162880262", "Github": "https://github.com/rdegges"}
```

So, I've also got an `index.html` template in Hugo that contains a navbar which looks like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    {{ range sort $title, $link := .Site.Params.navLinks }}
      <li><a href="{{ $link }}">{{ $title }}</a></li>
    {{ end }}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This above code works correctly, with one exception: I'd like to order the results of my links instead of having them randomly ordered each time.

I know that Maps are not inherently structured in Go -- but is there a way to retain the original ordering of my navigation elements in some way?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't use a map but a slice. Dead simple.

Comment: Would you mind posting an example of how to make it work with a slice? I'm quite new to Go templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go templates sort maps by key. If you want to force a specific order, then use a slice:

Here's the YAML:

```
baseurl: "https://www.rdegges.com/"
languageCode: "en-us"
title: "Randall Degges"
params:
    navLinks: 
        - title: Twitter
          url: https://twitter.com/rdegges
        - title: Facebook
          url: https://www.facebook.com/rdegges
```

... and the template:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    {{ range $link := .Site.Params.navLinks }}
      <li><a href="{{ $link.url }}">{{ $link.title }}</a></li>
    {{ end }}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful, and saved me <3 Really appreciate the assist!

Comment: Go maps have no guaranteed order.

Comment: @CodingPickle - no, that is not true. The Go template engine does nothing magic out-of-the-box with the datastructures given, so a Go map is a ... Go map. And since Go 1.1, the order of the keys when you range over a Go map has not been guaranteed. It may seem consistent, but it isn't.

Comment: It looks to me like the template maintainers added sorting by default to the {{range}} action back in 2012. Take a look at this [github commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/a5950df89e129e93f76aa8391f84beb460ef82be). Am I reading this wrong?