# How to force the order of the annotations in a custom alert template (instead of alphabetical order) in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, go-templates

I am trying to setup a custom template for my alerts, but I found that whenever I loop through the annotations, it keeps on showing them in alphabetical order instead of the order I initially configured in my alerts. Any ideas on how to fix this, or force some sort of order while looping through the annotations?

Thanks

```
{{ define "custom_alert" }}
Status: {{ .Status }} 
{{ range .Alerts }} {{ range $k, $v := .Annotations }}
{{ $k }}: {{ $v }} {{ end }} {{ end }}
URL: {{ .DashboardURL }}
{{ end }}
```

[image]

Comment: Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33860961#comment76560806_33862260) under somewhat related answer and my (rather minuscule) understanding of go maps, I assume order of annotations is not preserved.